How can I fix the next code in Julia so I try to program a function that generates samples without replace?
I have the next code in Julia but the problem is when I use the vector
p = [0.2,0.1,0.1,0.15,0.17] with n = 3

appears the next:

BoundsError: attempt to access 4-element Vector{Float64} at index [5]

Could you help me?
function sin_reemplazo(p,n)
    if !(isa(p,Vector) && isa(n,Int) && n>0 && n ≤ length(p))
        @error "p debe ser un vector, n un entero positivo y n menor que la longitud del vector p"
        return nothing
    end
    p ./sum(p)  #Normalizo las probabilidades
    @warn "Los valores del vector p fueron forzados a sumar 1"
    muestra1 = []
    disponible = collect(1:length(p))
    for _ in 1:n
        u = rand()
        cum_sum = 0.0
        seleccionado = 0
        for j in 1:length(disponible)
            cum_sum += p[disponible[j]]
            if u ≤ cum_sum
                seleccionado = disponible[j]
                
                break
            end
        end

        push!(muestra1,seleccionado)
        indice_a_remover = findfirst(==(seleccionado), disponible)
        if indice_a_remover !== nothing
            deleteat!(disponible, indice_a_remover)
        end

        if !isempty(disponible)
            # Filtra y normaliza el vector 'p' basado en los elementos disponibles
            p_disponibles = p[disponible]  # Extrae las probabilidades para los elementos disponibles
            p = p_disponibles ./ sum(p_disponibles)  # Normaliza el vector de probabilidades
        end
       
    end
    return ("muestra sin reemplazo: ", muestra1)
end


Why are you re-normalizing by the remaining elements every loop? That's definitely going to not be sampling without replacement in any regular sense.
Putting that aside, the issue is how you're sampling. You're deleting an index from disponible and then getting an error because you're no longer able to access a 5th element that you've deleted because it's only 4 elements long. I'd really reconsider what the function needs to be doing here. If you're just looking to get a random sample, I'd use StatsBase and say sample(p, n; replace=false).

Let me understand, you want to sample without replacement n integers in the range 1:m provided a vector of m elements describing the probability of each element (i.e. the PMF), right?

Also, are you looking for a ready available lib function or the objective is to implement the algo yourself?

I think you mean to select using a distribution to bias selection, but to serially remove the found bias entries from consideration if selection is without replacement.
Your problem is that you are shrinking the array, so the results go out of bounds. You should just zero the distribution entries to prevent their re-use, prior to re-normalizing the distribution:
using LinearAlgebra

function seleccionar_usando_distribución(p, n; sin_reemplazo = true)
    @assert(!sin_reemplazo || length(p) >= n)
    probs = deepcopy(p)
    muestral = zeros(Int, n)
    for i = 1:n
        x = rand()
        j = findfirst(>(x), accumulate(+, normalize(probs)))
        muestral[i] = j
        if sin_reemplazo
            probs[j] = zero(probs[j])
        end
    end
    return muestral
end

@show seleccionar_usando_distribución([0.2,0.1,0.1,0.15,0.17], 3)
@show seleccionar_usando_distribución([0.2,0.1,0.1,0.15,0.17], 3, sin_reemplazo = false)

Yields for one example run:
seleccionar_usando_distribución([0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.17], 3) = [1, 2, 4]
seleccionar_usando_distribución([0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.17], 3, sin_reemplazo = false) = [1, 1, 1]

